# Mailchimp Extension - not recognising API key

Tags: mailchimp

I've installed mailchimp on a site (drupal 7.59, civi 4.6.33)

I have 
Created an API key in Mailchimp
Copy/pasted API key to mailchimp settings in CiviCRM

And on clicking save/test get the following message

Could not use the Mailchimp API - API Key required. You will see this message If you have not yet configured your Mailchimp acccount.

Anyone else had this issue? Which blindingly obvious step have I missed out?

Answer (score 1):

Looked on the github issues column and found this

https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/300

Latest version of mailchimp extension (2.0.1) not necessarily compatible with civi 4.6